# Помогите исправить ошибку с удалением строки из файла путем перезаписи

Tags: c, файлы

Такая проблема...
Написал код и не вижу ошибки из-за отсутствия опыта.

Язык C(Си)
В этот раз кодил через visual studio.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>//При просмотре списков количество строк не совпадает.ИСПРАВИТЬ
#include<locale.h>//Сделать запись в файл и чтение из файла
#include<stdlib.h>//Удаление списков
#include<string.h>//Сделать таблицу на выводе
#include<conio.h>//Сделать таблицу на выводе
#define MAX 150
#define AVER 40
#define MIN 10
void N1_READ(void), N2_WRITE(void), N3_DELETE(void), REMOVE(void), SCAN_STR(void), DELETE_(void);
int MENU_select(void);
struct GD
{
    //ПЕРЕМЕННЫЕ СТРУКТУРЫ
    char data_0[MIN];//---------дата отправки------ 
    char time_A[MIN];//---------время отправки-----
    char A[AVER];//---------------место отправки-----
    char data_1[MIN];//---------дата прибытия------
    char time_B[MIN];//---------время прибытия-----
    char B[AVER];//---------------место прибытия-----
    int N_B[MIN];//--------------количество билетов-
    double price[MIN];//---------стоимость билета---
};
int main(void)
{
    system("color 2");
    system("chcp 1251");//ПЕРЕМННЫЕ
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    int y = 1;//счетчики
    char tab2[10] = "yes";//для сравнения
    char tab3[10] = "yes";
    char tabk[] = "yes";//символов
    while (y)
    {
        switch (MENU_select())
        {
        case 1:N2_WRITE(); break;//-------------------------------------------------------------------ДОБАВЛЕНИЕ В СПИСОК
        case 2:N1_READ(); break;//------------------------------------------------------------------------ПРОСМОТР СПИСКА
        case 3:N3_DELETE(); break;//-------------------------------------------------------------------УДАЛЕНИЕ ИЗ СПИСКА
        case 4:system("cls"); system("PAUSE"); exit(0); break;//---------------------------------------ВЫХОД ИЗ ПРОГРАММЫ
        }
    }
}
//================================================МЕНЮ
int MENU_select(void)
{
    int c;
    char s[80];
    system("cls");//МЕНЮ
    printf("|===========MENU===========|\n");
    printf("|1|===Добавление  списка===|\n");
    printf("|2|====Просмотр  списка====|\n");
    printf("|3|===Удаление из списка===|\n");
    printf("|4|===Выход из программы===|\n");
    printf("|==========================|\n");
    printf("|=Выберите номер  варианта=|\n");
    printf("|==========================|\n");
    s[79] = '\0';
    do
    {
        printf("Вариант: ");
        gets_s(s, 80);
        c = atoi(s);
    } while (c < -MAX || c>MAX);
    return c;
}
//==============================================ЧТЕНИЕ
void N1_READ(void)
{
    char tab1[10] = "yes";
    char tabk[] = "yes";//символов
    int j = 0;
    while (j == 0)
    {

        system("cls");
        printf("Данные:\n");
        printf("---+---------------+---------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+---------+---------+\n");
        printf(" № |     Откуда    |      Куда     | Дата и время отправления |   Дата и время прибытия  | Билетов | Цена/руб|\n");
        printf("---+---------------+---------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+---------+---------+\n");
        SCAN_STR();
        printf("\nВыйти?(yes): ");//---Выход из просмотра
        scanf_s("%s", tab1, 10);
        if (*tab1 == *tabk)
        {
            j = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            j = 0;
        }
    }
}
//==============================================ЗАПИСЬ
void N2_WRITE(void)
{
    char tabk[] = "yes";//символов
    char tab2[10] = "yes";//для сравнения
    struct GD otv[MIN];//ЖД 
    int t = 0, f = 0, k = 0;
    FILE* file = fopen("data.txt", "a+");
    for (int i = t; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        system("cls");
        printf("Ввод данных о ЖД номер %d:\n", i + 1);
        fprintf(file, " %d ", i + 1);
        printf("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
        fprintf(stdout, "Введите точку отбытия: ");//-----A[MAX]-точка А
        scanf_s("%s", otv[i].A, AVER);
        fprintf(file, "|%15s", otv[i].A);
        fprintf(stdout, "Введите точку прибытия: ");//--------B[MAX]-точка Б
        scanf_s("%s", otv[i].B, AVER);
        fprintf(file, "|%15s", otv[i].B);
        printf("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
        fprintf(stdout, "Введите дату отбытия: ");//------data_0-дата отправления
        scanf_s("%s", otv[i].data_0, 15);
        fprintf(file, "|%15s", otv[i].data_0);
        fprintf(stdout, "Введите время отбытия: ");//-----time_A-время А
        scanf_s("%s", otv[i].time_A, MIN);
        fprintf(file, "|%10s", otv[i].time_A);
        printf("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
        fprintf(stdout, "Введите дату прибытия: ");//---------data_1-дата отправления
        scanf_s("%s", otv[i].data_1, 15);
        fprintf(file, "|%15s", otv[i].data_1);
        fprintf(stdout, "Введите время прибытия: ");//-------time_B-время Б
        scanf_s("%s", otv[i].time_B, MIN);
        fprintf(file, "|%10s", otv[i].time_B);
        printf("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
        fprintf(stdout, "Введите количество билетов: ");//----N_B-количество билетов
        scanf_s("%d", otv[i].N_B);
        fprintf(file, "|%9d", *otv[i].N_B);
        fprintf(stdout, "Стоимость билета: ");//--------------price-стоимость
        scanf_s("%lf", otv[i].price);
        fprintf(file, "|%9.2lf|+\n", *otv[i].price);
        printf("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
        printf("продолжить ввод?(yes для продолжения/no для завершения)\n");
        scanf_s("%s", tab2, 10);//скан ответа
        if (*tabk != *tab2)//не yes/конец
        {
            i = 149;
            k++;
            t++;
            system("cls");
        }
        if (*tabk == *tab2)//yes
        {
            k++;//Счетчик для того,чтобы не выводилось больше списков,чем нужно
            t++;
        }

    }
    fclose(file);
}
//============================================УДАЛЕНИЕ
void N3_DELETE(void)
{
    char tab3[10] = "yes";
    char tabk[] = "yes";//символов
    system("cls");
    printf("1-удаление файла\n");
    printf("2-удаление cтроки\n");
    printf("3-Выход\n");
    int o;
    printf("Выбор: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &o);
    switch (o)
    {
    case 1:REMOVE(); break;//Удаление файла
    case 2:DELETE_(); break;
    case 3:break;//Отмена
    }
}
//======================================УДАЛЕНИЕ ФАЙЛА
void REMOVE(void)
{
    int m = 0;
    char tab3[10] = "yes";
    char tabk[] = "yes";//символов
    system("cls");
    printf("Очистить файл?(yes/no): ");
    scanf_s("%s", tab3, 10);
    if (*tab3 == *tabk)
    {
        system("cls");
        if (remove("data.txt") == EOF)
        {
            printf("Ошибка, файл не очищен!");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Файл успешно удален!\n");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        system("cls");
    }
    system("PAUSE");
}
//=======================================ФАЙЛ В СТРОКИ
void SCAN_STR(void)//До сюда все норм
{
    struct GD otv[MIN];
    char str[MAX][MAX];
    FILE* file = fopen("data.txt", "a+");//Изменить значение
    int k, f = 0, p = 0;
    for (int y = 0; y < MAX; y++)
    {
        int i = 0, n = 0;
        while ((k = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
        {

            if (k != '\+')
            {
                str[y][i] = k;
                i++;
            }
            if (k == '\+')
            {
                f++; n = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (n == 1)
        {
            str[y][i] = '\0';
        }
    }
    for (int y = 0; y < MAX; y++)
    {
        if (f != p)
        {
            printf("%s\n", str[y]);
            printf("---+---------------+---------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+---------+---------+");
            p++;

        }
    }
    fclose(file);
}
//=====================================УДАЛЕНИЕ СТРОКИ
void DELETE_(void)
{
    int j = 1;
    while (j == 1)
    {
        remove("win.txt");
        char str_del[MAX][MAX];
        FILE* file = fopen("data.txt", "a+");//Изменить значение
        FILE* baza = fopen("win.txt", "a+");
        int k, f = 0, p = 0;
        for (int y = 0; y < MAX; y++)
        {
            int i = 0, n = 0;
            while ((k = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
            {
                if (k != '\+')
                {
                    str_del[y][i] = k;
                    i++;
                }
                if (k == '\+')
                {
                    f++; n = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (n == 1)
            {
                str_del[y][i] = '\0';
            }
        }
        system("cls");
        printf("Данные: \n");
        printf("---+---------------+---------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+---------+---------+\n");
        for (int y = 0; y < MAX; y++)
        {
            if (f != p)
            {
                if (*str_del[y] != '\0')
                {
                    printf("%s\n", str_del[y]);
                    printf("---+---------------+---------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+---------+---------+");
                    p++;
                }
            }
        }
        int N_D_S;//Номер удаляемой строки
        printf("\nВведите номер Удаляемой строки(1111для выхода):");
        scanf_s("%d", &N_D_S);
        N_D_S = N_D_S - 1;
        p = 0; int y = 0;
        while (f != p)
        {
            if (y != N_D_S)
            {
                fputs(str_del[y], baza);
                fputs("+", baza);
            }
            y++; p++;
        }
        fprintf(baza, "\n");//==========================================================ДО СЮДА
        fclose(file);
        fclose(baza);
        remove("data.txt");
        if (rename("win.txt", "data.txt") == EOF)
            printf("ОШИБКА!!!");
        else
            printf("-------------------------------------------\n");
        if (N_D_S == 1111 - 1)
        {
            j = 0; break;
        }
        system("\nPAUSE");
    }
}
```

Проблема вот такая.
Практически внизу кода есть функция void DELETE_.

Вот в ней есть часть кода отвечающая за запись в временный файл, после которой идет перезапись в первоначальный файл.А потом выводится таблица без номера выбранной мною строки.
Но если я ввожу 1 строку, то первая строка просто пустая.

Приложу скриншоты проблемы:
[image: ^При вводе значений кроме 1 идет все нормально, и код работает и я доволен.^]
^При вводе значений кроме 1 идет все нормально, и код работает и я доволен.^
[image: Но если на вход поступает единица, то все просто едет.]
^При вводе 1 таблица начинает ехать.^
[image: Вот это мне нужно и исправить!]
^Вот это мне нужно подправить,что-бы было все ровно^

Может ошибка в какой либо мелочи...
Думаю нормально объяснил,спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Дело в том, что в массиве str_del строки начиная со 2-й начинаются с символа '\n', который идет после + в конце строки. Поэтому в файл добавляется лишняя пустая строка.

Соответственно проблема в чтении данных в этом куске кода. Зачем '+' на конце? непонятно. Читайте строку до символа '\n' и ошибка исчезнет.

```
while ((k = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
            {
                if (k != '\n')
                {
                    str_del[y][i] = k;
                    i++;
                }
                if (k == '\n')
                {
                    f++; n = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Вообще не понятно, зачем вы данные храните в файле сразу с разметкой. Храните там серию чисел через пробел, а форматирование зададите при выводе.

И да. Используйте пошаговое выполнение и брекпойнты.

Comment: Спасибо, все пошло, благодарен вам очень